# cannot exec 'anything' : no such file or directory screen

Tags: bash, files, screen

I’m running some call of duty game servers with screen.

I have a `start.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

user=cabe
game=cod
verision=cod1.5
server=xxx.xx.xxx:28970
mod=
ip=xxx.xx.xxx
port=28970
punkbuster=1
slots=20


# Don't Change This
. /mnt/utilities/files/games/cod/1.5/files/extra/scripts/startup/cod/start_cod
```

and it is linked up to this

```
cd /home/$user/$game/$verision/$server ./stop.sh screen -A -m -d -S $port /home/$user/$game/$verision/$server/cod_lnxded +set net_ip $ip
+set net_port $port +set dedicated 2 +set sv_punkbuster $punkbuster +set sv_maxclients $slots +exec myserver.cfg +set fs_basepath /home/$user/$game/$verision/$server +set fs_homepath /home/$user/$game/$verision/$server
```

Now every time I run `start.sh`, it gives me:

```
Cannot exec 'quit': No such file in directory
```

So I went and see, if I did something wrong in my stop script, but I can't see what’s wrong. I’ve this this exact script in another machine but on this new one It just won't work.

`stop.sh` looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

user=cabe
game=cod
verision=cod1.5
server=xxx.xx.xxx:28970


# Don't Change This
. /mnt/utilities/files/games/cod/1.5/files/extra/scripts/startup/cod/stop2
```

and is linked to the script:

```
cd /home/$user/$game/$verision/$server
screen -S $port -X quit
```

Now anything I put behind `-X` will say `Cannot exec 'blabla'`.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your stop script does not define port (check the start script, that one does, and this is missing). So when you run the `screen -S $port -X quit` command, it looks like ($port is not defined so it results in a blank string):

```
screen -S -X quit
```

Screen interprets this as "set the session name to -X, then run the `quit` command inside a shell".

If you had the port, it would look like:

```
screen -S 28970 -X quit
```

this means "send the `quit` screen action to the session named 28970", which is what you actually want.

So in order to fix it, simply ensure your `stop.sh` script has `port` defined.

Learn more about screen command line parameters:

https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Invoking-Screen

Comment: I see! Thanks. I did change so it said $server instead of $port and then it worked. But i would still like to have the screen named with the port :p Ill try ur

Comment: The mistake would have been avoided (to some extent) or more obvious, if `$port` was quoted (like this: `screen -S "$port" -X quit`), leading to an empty session name instead of `-X` being interpreted as session name.